# Firebase Firestore: globally detect when there are pending writes

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, onbeforeunload

I've got a simple requirement to show a warning to the user if they leave the browser window while a pending write is happening in Firestore using a beforeunload listener:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', e => {
  if (NO_PENDING_SAVES) return;      

  e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue =
    'Your changes are still being saved. Are you sure you want to leave?';
}, {
  capture: true,
});
```

In Firestore using the Web SDK, how do I detect whether there are pending saves or not globally? There is a [waitForPendingWrites()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore#waitForPendingWrites()) method on the Firestore object, but it would require polling and it's also asynchronous, so it won't work inside of `beforeunload`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved doing this (async way) using Angular Framework and dependency `"@angular/fire": "^7.4.1"` :

```
export class FirebaseService {
 constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
 }
 pendingWrites(): Observable<any> {
    return defer(() => this.db.firestore.waitForPendingWrites())
 }
```

And then:

```
export class PendingWritesService {
 hasPendingWrites$: Observable<boolean>;

 constructor(
  private firebaseService: FirebaseService
 ){
  this.hasPendingWrites$ = this.somethingPending$();
 }

 somethingPending$(): Observable<boolean> {
  const timeEmmiter = timer(1000);
  return race(timeEmmiter, this.firebaseService.pendingWrites()).pipe(
    switchMap((pendingWrites, noPendingWrites) => {
     const arePendingsWrites = 0;
      return of(pendingWrites === arePendingsWrites);
   })
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: What language is this in, and which SDK are you using?

Comment: @JohnnyOshika I answered your question in the main answer.